# Upload photo to server folder in PHP with Android

Tags: php, android, json

I want save photos in my server but inside of other folder. The structure of the folder is:

```
---main folder
 |
 ---uploadphoto.php
 |
 ---photos (folder)
  |
  --$email (folder)
```

When a user registers, I create a folder with the username with permissions 0777, and the folder is create successfully.

When I try upload a photo inside the user folder, it doesn't work, but if I change the path to save the file to, it works perfectly. This means outside of user folder, in folder "photos".

This is my php code to save the photos inside the folder:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ruta = "photos/". $email . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotoUp']['tmp_name'], $ruta))
    chmod ("photos/". $email . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']), 0644);
```

And the user name is passed through Android:

```
List<NameValuePair> paramsu = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
paramsu.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
paramsu.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", path));

JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(UPLOAD_PHOTO_URL, "POST", paramsu);
```

How can I put the photos inside the folder? I think it's a problem with the PHP syntax. I've debugged in Android and the variable email content the correct email to the PHP.

The way to create the folder is when register users.

```
$folderemail = $_POST['email']; 
    mkdir("photos/$folderemail", 0777);
    chmod("photos/$folderemail", 0644);
```

---

This is my file now:

```
$email = "$_POST['email']";
$ruta = "photos/". $email . "/" . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotoUp']['tmp_name'], $ruta))
    chmod ($ruta . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']), 0644);
```

I've tried also:

```
$email = "$_POST['email']";
$ruta = "photos/$email/" . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotoUp']['tmp_name'], $ruta))
    chmod ($ruta . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']), 0644);
```

and this:

```
//$email = "$_POST['email']";
$ruta = "photos/1234/" . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotoUp']['tmp_name'], $ruta))
    chmod ($ruta . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']), 0644);
```

This works perfectly but when I put the variable $email with the same name doesn't work.

The part of the application is this:

```
List<NameValuePair> paramsu = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
paramsu.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
paramsu.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", filename));

Log.d("request!", "starting");

JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
     UPLOAD_PHOTO_URL, "POST", paramsu);

Log.i("tag", email);//DEBUG (Email that upload the photo)
```

The Log.i returns the correct email test "1234".

When I create the email folder in the server works with this command in php:

```
$folderemail = $_POST['email']; 
mkdir("photos/$folderemail", 0777);
```

Comment: what is the user folder name, is it from $user or $email

Comment: Yes is $email, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: My server is on Ubuntu Server, but I'm trying with email without @ because I have to know how can I save the photos into the folder.

Comment: When I change the php script and put the real folder /photos/1234/ the file is uploaded inside this folder but when I change to /photos/$mail/ not. Why?

Comment: at this point you should post the whole script and I will reproduce it

Comment: The PHP to upload photo is the four lines of my post. This is the whole script. The Android application calls to this script and it must save the photo into the folder. Only works save it inside the folder photos but not in photos/$email.

Comment: are you creating the folder before uploading it?

Comment: yes, when the app register a new user, the php to save the user in MySQL also crete the folder

Comment: I've tried to view what returns `code basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);`and it is empty. What's the meaning of basename?

Comment: Base name is the name of the file so if you have `/some/path/to/filename.jpg` then basename would return just filename. U still need help with that

Comment: Yes, I still have the same problem. I do not get to save the photos in the folder, But if I put in PHP script the name of folder it's saved correctly `"/photos/1234/"`. When I put `"/photos/$email/"` or `"/photos".$email."/"` the photos aren't saved. And $email for the test is 1234.

Comment: Somebody has the solution, cos doesn't works...

Comment: I have this PHP error `Undefined index: email on line 15`

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$ruta = "photos/". $email . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
```

to

```
$ruta = "photos/$email/".basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the photo is saved in photos folder, not email folder and I don't know why...

Comment: @UKAndroid Did you fix this line to`chmod ("photos/". $email . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']), 0644);` ?

Comment: No I've tried change this lines and comment this line, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a slash missing between the username "$email" and the name of the file. So your essentially storing it like this:

when

```
$email = "john@apple.com";
```

then

```
$ruta = "/photos/john@apple.comfoto1.jpeg";
```

---

So add ."/". after $email in the ruta variable wich will make it like this:

```
$ruta = "photos/". $email . "/" . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
```

---

P.s. try to avoid CHMOD 0777, this will cause serious security vulnerabilities. Try to use 644 instead (with PHP running as the same user as the virtualhost UID)

Comment: It doesn't work. The photos is saving in /photos folder not /photos/$email folder. I can try with the email "1234" and it is sent to PHP file, but it is not saved in correct folder.

This is my file now:
 

    $email = "$_POST['email']";
    $ruta = "photos/". $email . "/" . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotoUp']['tmp_name'], $ruta))
        chmod ($ruta . basename( $_FILES['fotoUp']['name']), 0644);

Comment: check if the created dir is writable by hardcoding the filename into $ruta just to test. Make sure that it works and then check that you are not glueing the wrong name together by echoing $ruta with your orinal code. Also, you are adding the fotoUP name var twice to $ruta. Just use chmod($ruta, 0644);  (but that is not the main issue here)

Comment: I've checked the first PHP file to create the folder and the permissions. I've created with 777 permissions but when I enter in my server this folder has no su permissions and this is the problem.
<<<<
$folderemail = $_POST['email']; 
        mkdir("photos/$folderemail", 0777);
        chmod("$folderemail/", 0777);
>>>>
How can I change the way to create the folder to obtain all the permission to save the photo correctly.

Comment: These are the permission that appears:  www-data